# I have been trying to extract data from YouTube API and i'm getting a key word error "statistics" how to get rid of this error

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

This is the code

```
def get_channel_data(youtube, channel_id):
    request = youtube.channels().list(part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics", id=channel_id)
    responce = request.execute()
    data = dict(
        channel_name=responce["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"],
        views=responce["items"][0]["snippet"]["statistics"]["viewCount"],
        subscriber=responce["items"][0]["snippet"]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"],
        total_video=responce["items"][0]["snippet"]["statistics"]["videoCount"],
    )

    return data


get_channel_data(youtube, channel_id)
```

Comment: can you provide the content of _responce_ ? e.g. by print(responce) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `print(responce["items"][0])` to see what the item looks like, but even without that or docs, considering you're requesting `"snippet,contentDetails,statistics"`, I'd expect the statistics not to be "under" `snippet`.

Then, refactoring a bit to remove some of the repetition, we'd get

```
def get_channel_data(youtube, channel_id):
    request = youtube.channels().list(part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics", id=channel_id)
    responce = request.execute()
    first_item = responce["items"][0]
    first_snippet = first_item["snippet"]
    first_stats = first_item["statistics"]
    return {
        "channel_name": first_snippet["title"],
        "views": first_stats["viewCount"],
        "subscriber": first_stats["subscriberCount"],
        "total_video": first_stats["videoCount"],
    }


get_channel_data(youtube, channel_id)
```